# Visual Studio Code Surround With

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find any way to surround a selection with something in VS Code.

For example doing something like that : `text` => `"text"` just by selecting the word text and typing key <kbd>"</kbd>

Another example with the following text :

```
mon
tue
wed
thu
fri
sat
sun
```

By selecting all of theses words :

```
mon|
tue|
wed|
thu|
fri|
sat|
sun|
```

and typing <kbd>"</kbd> I would like to perform something like this :

```
"mon"
"tue"
"wed"
"thu"
"fri"
"sat"
"sun"
```

Comment: Alternative approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44793837/55246

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Selecting some text and pressing <kbd>"</kbd> already works in VSCode to surround a single item, and works for multi-line selections as well.

**NOTE**: this is **language dependent**. The language syntax must define opening and closing braces, e.g. quotes, braces, etc. So this will not work in a "plaintext" file, for example. Change your language mode with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `Change Language Mode` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and select something like JavaScript where this is supported.

What you are after though is not really that efficient like that. Your best bet is to use multi-cursors.

Place the cursor at the start of the first line, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to add another cursor below on the next line. Keep doing that until you have a cursor in front of all your words.

Then just type <kbd>"</kbd> then <kbd>END</kbd> then <kbd>"</kbd> and all your lines are surrounded by quotes.

NB: To check if you have a key bound, and what it is, you can always press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `Add Cursor Below` and if there's a keybinding it will show to the right of that text.

Comment: as far as I can see this works only to enquote something - the answer below is more like Visual Studio ctrl-k-s that allows selections to be surrounded with say, a try-catch block - don't know anything about the extension below but seems well rated in VS Code extension library

Comment: NOTE: This will not work if you use an extension such as Vim mode which changes key bindings behavior, until you disable the extension and restart VS Code.

Comment: For Mac users, the key binding is Command + Option + Down

Comment: I modified the try/catch for python: "snippet": "try: \n\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\nexcept Exception as e: \n\tprint(f'error here: {e}')$1\n$0"

Comment: Didn't work for json. Language-dependent solutions are obviously somewhat limited as solutions. This is a great example of something trivially easy to automate in emacs.

Answer (score 68):

In VS Code hold <kbd>Command + Shift + P</kbd>
then write:
"> Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"

In this area that you are allowed to modify, paste this inside the brackets:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+p",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "\"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}\""
    }
}
```

** note that in this example the *key* is set to <kbd>Ctrl + p</kbd>, you can change the *key* to whatever you prefer

Comment: This is the cleanest solution without having to install any additional plugins.

Comment: This doesn't work. It surrounds the text with a double quote. Can't see how you can specify a tag or any other kind of text.

Comment: This is the real response to the question. Should be the first in the list. 
By the way @ATL_DEV: if you want to wrap it with a different thing than double-quites (the question was about this specifically), then simply change the double-quotes in the snippet with a different thing.

Comment: This is great. Also, just change it to `"snippet": "${1}${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}${1}"` to be able to insert any arbitrary character.

Comment: @Aurelio How do you pass the variable to

Comment: @Aurelio you get the cursor to ${1} and write whatever you need after activating the shortcut it gets replicated wherever the ${1} is in the snippettemplate

Answer (score 36):

Maybe you can try this extension, you can write your own custom wrappers:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yatki.vscode-surround

> A simple yet powerful extension to add wrapper templates around your code blocks.

Features

- Supports **multi** selections
- Fully **customizable**
- **Custom** wrapper functions
- You can assign **shortcuts** for *each* wrapper function separately
- Nicely formated

#### Demo 1: Choosing wrapper function from quick pick menu

[image: Demo 1]

#### Demo 2: Wrapping multi selections

[image: Demo 2]

Comment: Helped me to surround my 2k of rows with single quotes. Few notes that worth mentioning:
1. Use [multiple selection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor) to select data
2. Create custom snippet according to docs: 
`"singleQuotes": { "label": "single quotes", "description": "Single Quotes", "snippet": "'$TM_SELECTED_TEXT'" },`
3. Use custom snippet to wrapp your text

Comment: if you are looking for double quotes here is the code `{
    "surround.custom": {
      "doubleQuotes": {
        "label": "double Quotes",
        "description": "doubleQuotes",
        "snippet": "\"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}\""
      }
    }
  }`

Answer (score 20):

Using Yuri Aps' suggestion, I added the following JSON to keybindings.json. This provides the functionality Ronan Lamour requested for any file type, and without requiring an extension. It works for either single or multiple selections when using either single or double quotes. Coming from Sublime, this is helpful since it reproduces functionality Sublime provides natively.

```
{
    "key": "'",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorHasSelection",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "'${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}'"
    }
},
{
    "key": "shift+'",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorHasSelection",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "\"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}\""
    }
},
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. Thanks Kirk!

Comment: ` || editorHasMultipleSelections` does not add anything to the `when` clause and can be removed.  `editorHasSelection ` is true when there are multiple selections.

Comment: Mark, I got your suggested edits but I don't have enough reputation to review them.  =(

Answer (score 8):

### Update 15-02-2022:

VS Code has introduced [Surround with snippets for JS/TS](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_surround-with-snippets-for-jsts) natively.

It may not be totally related with the question but it may help someone who landed in this question with the intent of "surround with" in vs code.

Comment: Does not work with ad hoc snippets.

Comment: @majkinetor yes it does  "add quote": {
  "prefix": "q",
  "body": ["\"$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0\"",
  ],
  "description": "Quote"
 }

Comment: Does that work in general or just for JS/TS @MotKohn ?

Comment: Of interest, with VSCode 1.70 (July 2022): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150678

Comment: it is not a new snippet feature, they just changed the JS/TS snippets to use the `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}` variable as all the other answers here use

Answer (score 6):

I was coming from (neo)vim switching to VS Code, and was using Tim Pope's wonderful "vim-surround" plugin for vim before. I found a port of that plugin for VS Code. It's very useful, and incredibly efficient once you learn the shortcuts, in my opinion!

Links:

- [Original plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) by Tim Pope for vim
- [Port of plugin](https://github.com/benferse/vscode-surround) to VS Code

If you use vim or vim bindings in VS Code, please enjoy!

Edit: the [VSCodeVim plugin](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) includes the surround functionality automatically, so if you have that plugin installed, you don't really need the `vscode-surround` plugin.

Comment: VSCodeVim's surround ability is just as good as vim-surround in nvim

Comment: @Reorx yep, it's already in my edit since 2018. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This extension also exists if you want custom surround with text.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sifue.surrounding.

I just installed it and got it working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

A  more generic solution:  in `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",     
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorHasSelection",
  "args": {
      "snippet": "$1${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1$0"
  }
}
```

Whatever you type after triggering the keybinding will be added to both ends of all selections.

[image: surround demo]

Just <kbd>tab</kbd> to the end of the word(s) when you are done and, if you had multiple cursors <kbd>Esc</kbd> to remove extra cursors leaving just one.

Answer (score 1):

Select the word you want to surround it with and enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Then just key in whatever key you want to surround it with.

Comment: Works for me but without the Ctrl + Alt + T command, just select and press either ", (, [, { , etc

Answer (score 0):

Since GitHub [supports math](https://github.blog/2022-05-19-math-support-in-markdown) in Markdown now, I need to wrap my formulas with dollar signs:

```
$E = mc^2$
```

When I select a formula and press dollar sign `$` on my keyboard I get my formula wrapped automatically. Here is one way to achieve it:

1. Open **Keyboard Shortcuts** menu:

[image]

2. Press on **Open Keyboards Shortcuts (JSON)** button:

[image]

3. In `shortucts.json` file, which opens, paste this snippet:

```json
{
    "key": "shift+4",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorHasSelection",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "$${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting in vs code
File -> preferences -> settings

Type in "auto surrond" and turn it on for "Language Defined"

Check
[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to0bV.png) or this [Youtube tutorial by Code 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCh5w_Oo_ZA)

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?