# How to edit all lines in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a list of data to which I need to put a `'` symbol at the start of the line and at the end of the line. So the original data looks like this:

```
abcde
cdeab
deabc
eabcd
```

And I want all of the lines to look like this:

```
'abcde'
'cdeab'
'deabc'
'eabcd'
```

In my real data, I would have 10,000 of lines. So if I can do something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire document and then have some magic shortcut to change from selecting all lines to editing all lines that would be perfect!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You could edit and replace with a regex:

Find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>):

```
^(.+)$
```

Replace:

```
'$1'
```

This regex finds any content on a line and wraps it inside quotes. The `$1` refers to whatever is matched inside the parentheses in the regex. In this case, it's "one or more characters" i.e. everything on the line. Be sure to tick the regex icon.

[image: Video demonstration of the replacement]

If every line may or may not have a space before the content, and you want every line to have a space, try this:

Find:

```
^ ?(.+)$
```

Replace (notice the space before the first quote):

```
 '$1'
```

Comment: $0 worked for me.

Answer (score 40):

Here is an easy way to do this:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all or select your desired text.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to put a cursor at the end of each line.
3. Type your <kbd>'</kbd> (or whatever you want at the end).
4. <kbd>Home</kbd> will move all your cursors to the beginning of the lines.
5. Type your <kbd>'</kbd> (or whatever you want at the beginning of all the lines).

Comment: Really Helpful. Thanks so much

Comment: Actually I like this answer much more than this rated much higher!

Comment: @Mark it's not working with more than 10 thousand lines Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MalikBilal Which step is not working - the first?

Comment: @Mark every step is working but only the first 10 thousand lines got selected in a file. I have files of more than 40 thousand lines.

Comment: @MalikBilal Try clearing (or set to null) the setting `Search: Max Results` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut.

1. First press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> then click the mouse button on the first line.
2. Go to the last line, and then do the same.

This will mark all the parts of one side. Whatever you type will be reflected in the marked spaces.

Do the same on the other side too.

Comment: Holding Ctrl + Alt and clicking each line will allow you to finely select which lines (and what position within the line) to make the same edits.

Comment: This doesn't work on the right side (in LTR text); it's selecting arbitrary amounts of characters based on the position of the first selection.

Comment: I love this, just played around with it for a minute and it blew my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Toggle Multi curosr Modified` from action pane.

Select the cursor points with `ctrl` + `<Mouse click>` , you can modify everything simultaneously.

*This will require lots of manual efforts if lines are more*

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Find and Replace*.

Besides, paste to Excel and using a function to add character `'`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind - replace `abcde` with `'abcde'` line by using option `Find and Replace` option. I'm pretty sure Visual Studio Code has something similar to that.

Comment: but the thing is that the real data has different values. So I don't think this way is valid.

Comment: Assuming by your question you want something like IntelliJ IDEA offers (edit all the lines simultaneously), am I right?

Comment: I don't know about IntelliJ IDEA, but I want to edit all line at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Shift +Alt shortcut for windows and for Mac use Shift + Option

First press Alt + Shift/Shift + Option then click the mouse button on the first line.

This will mark all the parts of one side. Whatever you type will be reflected in the marked spaces.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place Cursor where you want to insert/delete text.
2. Goto Selection Menu and choose Column Selection Mode
3. Scroll to the bottom of the data and shift + click in the last line where you placed the first cursor.
4. Perform action (add/delete whatevs)
5. Repeat for whatever other areas you want to change.

v: 1.74.3

Answer (score -3):

1- You can use the Ctrl + H shortcut (menu *Edit* → *Replace*)

2. Enter abcde in *Find Control*.
3. Enter 'abcde' in *Replace Control*.
4. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Visual Studio Ctrl + H screenshot]

[image: Visual Studio Ctrl + Alt + Enter screenshot]

Comment: my code might not be clear, I have edit the case to make it clearer. This might be clearer for you that the data are different

Comment: There is an option to find by regular expression refer @cubrr's response.