# take each line of a list and create one long single lined string wrapped by speechmarks

Tags: regex

So essentially someone on our dev team made a bit of a big issue where they had changed all of the build actions on .csproj files and we are thinking of the easiest way to change them back.

We want to use regex to open all the csproj files via VSCode. The format to open multiple files in file explorer is

```
"filename" "filename1" "filename2"
```

my list is

```
com.Console.job1.csproj
com.Console.job2.csproj
com.Console.job3.csproj
com.Console.job4.csproj
```

my current regex

```
(.+)\n
```

then my regex to replace is

```
"$1"\s
```

which doesnt work at all

Comment: What do you mean by "regex to replace"? Regex is only used to *search for* matches. Replacement patterns only may contain placeholders like `$1`. What do you need to do with the file contents?

Comment: If you mean you want to wrap the lines with `"`s, just use `.+` and replace with `"$0"`.

Comment: Dupe of [How to edit all line in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793523/how-to-edit-all-line-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex :

**To locate pattern**

```
([^\s]+)(\n)?
```

**To replace :**

```
"$1"
```

keep in mind the replace pattern contains a space at its end

**Demo :**
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/S29vpJ/2)