# Visual Studio Code surround/wrap selected with custom function (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Android Studio Code (and I assume many other great editors) gives the option to select code and wrap either a custom function around or the most commonly used functions. For the custom functions, a window with a text line could appear in which you write the wrapping function.

Is there any comparable solution for Python in Visual Studio Code? It would increase the *workflow* significantly .

```py
"Hello" -> print("Hello") # Functions with a single parameter are wrapped around the selected text "Hello"

3+10 -> np.random.uniform(3+10,,) # The function is filled as much as possible with selected values

3+10,5,3 -> np.random.uniform(3+10,5,3) # Tuples are inserted directly into the function
```

The answer to the common question
[Visual Studio Code Surround With](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363030/visual-studio-code-surround-with#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20word%20you%20want,want%20to%20surround%20it%20with.)
brought the answer that it is language dependent and I a solutions for [Javascript](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_surround-with-snippets-for-jsts) and for [C in VisualCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-use-surround-with-code-snippets?view=vs-2022).

Comment: don't mix VS with VSC (C link), use `"$1(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT})$0"`, you can make `$1` have a few possible alternatives that you use often

Comment: Describe what steps you are looking for and the state of the editor at each step. Being somewhat abstract is okay. But right now it's not clear to me what the initial and final states you are looking for are.